# How to search for multiple strings in a file

Tags: bash, file, search, string

I want to search for the occurrence of string1 OR string2 OR string3, etc. in a file, and print only those lines (to stdout or a file, either one).  How can I easily do this in bash?

Comment: To find all of the strings inside a file, you can run grep in FOR loop: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462445/43233

Answer (score 18):

you can also use awk

```
awk '/string1|string2|string3/' file
```

With awk, you can also easily use AND logic if needed.

```
awk '/string1/ && /string2/ && /string3/' file
```

Answer (score 8):

```
grep "string1\|string2\|string3" file_to_search_in
```

Comment: Thanks, Chen, for your speedy reply.  Of course, that works - slick!

Answer (score 3):

One other choice, especially if the number of strings you want to search is large, is to put those strings into a file delimited by newlines and use:

```
grep -f file_of_strings file_to_search
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if /string1|string2|string3/;' file1 file2 *.fileext
```

With Bash one liner:

```
while read line; do if [[ $line =~ string1|string2 ]]; then echo $line; fi; done < file
```

With Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ string1|string2|string3 ]]; then
       echo $line
    fi
done < file
```

Note that the spaces around "[[ $line =~ string1|string2 ]]" are all relevant. ie these fail in Bash:

```
[[ $line=~string1|string2 ]] # will be alway true...
[[$line =~ string1|string2]] # syntax error
```

Comment: The curly braces can be omitted from your Bash one liner. The `do` and `done` do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
grep -e 'string1' -e 'string2' -e 'string3'
```

Comment: Thanks, Randy, worked like a charm!
And, meanwhile, I found one more:
egrep 'string1|string2' infile

Answer (score -1):

## Way:

awk '/Mbits/||/Gbits/{print}' 100P-TCP-f1.out